# Virtual box 4.3.30 Fails to Load OVA on Yosemite 10.10.4

Tags: macos, virtualbox, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to run a pre configured Debian machine on my Mac Pro with Yosemite 10.10.4 on using VirtualBox 4.3.30. I import the appliance successfully but when trying to start it I run into the following error:

Failed to open a session for the virtual machine XXX.

Unsupported version 17 of data unit 'cpum' (instance #1, pass 0xffffffff) (VERR_SSM_UNSUPPORTED_DATA_UNIT_VERSION).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: Console
Interface: IConsole {8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6}

It works fine with the 5.0.3 test version of VirtualBox, but I'd rather use the older version, and I really want to understand what's the problem.
I scoped around the VirtualBox's Mac Users forum but couldn't find anything useful.
Also, I had a friend of mine run it on her Mac air with Yosemite 10.10.2 on and it works fine, so I am guessing it is a problem of the last Yosemite release. But stil...

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Option click on the VM in the list, then select "discard saved state". Then boot the VM.